# What is the physical meaning of the functional π = U-W used in the variational approach to deriving the finite element equations of a system?

Tags: variational-calculus

In the variational formulation of the finite element equilibrium equations for a system, the functional π = U-W is used, for which we find stationary points in order to derive the governing equation of equilibrium (U = strain energy of the system and W = total potential of the loads). Can someone please explain what this functional represents physically?